# How can I use Javascript to iterate twice over an array element?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, loops, iteration

Please help! I need to declare an *empty array* (`foodTray = []`), and run a loop 5x (for each iteration push a food type), the foodTray has to hold a max of 2 types but the total length should not exceed 5.

`const foodTypes = ['seafood', 'nuts', 'seeds'];`

I had done this =>

```
'use strict';

let foodTray = [];
const foodTypes = ['seafood', 'nuts', 'seeds'];
for (let x = 0; x < foodTypes.length; x++) {
  const food = foodTypes[x];
  foodTray.push(food); 
  if (foodTray.length < 5) {
    foodTray.push(food); 
  }
}
console.log('I have ' + `${foodTray}.`);
```

but I was instructed the loop had to run 5 times***** and what I used was the length of the foodTypes.

The desired output should be => I have seafood, seafood, nuts, nuts, seeds.

The problem: I did `for (let x = 0; x < *foodTypes.length*; x++)`
instead, the loop should run 5 times! I am not sure how I can iterate twice over an element.

Comment: Could you please clarify what's the problem and what is the desired output?

Comment: Well it seems your code is working fine and you are getting your desired output, what is the problem?

Comment: do you mean to add the first 5 twice? if you want it to run over the first 5 foodtypes you could change the for loop : for (let x = 0; x < foodTypes.length && x < 5; x++) but I'm not sure I understand the desired output..

Comment: perhaps you could count the number of `food` in your `foodtray` and add it to your `if` statement? `while (foodTray.length < 5 && foodTray.filter(f => f == food).length < 2) { foodTray.push(food)}`

Answer (score 3):

Your original code is giving you the desired output which is : I have seafood, seafood, nuts, nuts, seeds.

```js
let foodTray = [];
const foodTypes = ['seafood', 'nuts', 'seeds'];
for (let x = 0; x < foodTypes.length; x++) {
  const food = foodTypes[x];
  foodTray.push(food); 
  if (foodTray.length < 5) {
    foodTray.push(food); 
  }
}
console.log('I have ' + `${foodTray}.`);
```